# Sublime SFTP + Rails + DigitalOcean -- Uploading Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, sftp, digital-ocean

Recently had the pleasure of picking up a VPS over @ DigitalOcean. It's a Ubuntu 14.04 running Rails + Nginx & Unicorn.

I wanted to work with Sublime, as I have locally, so I installed the commercial SFTP plugin. I was able to successfully gain remote access to my VPS, and I even downloaded the rails folder locally. Now is where it gets difficult though, and I need some help.

How I do I keep the local folder and the remote folder in sync?

Right clicking on the folder via Sublime offers some options like, `sync Local -> Remote`, which seems like what I want, except that every upload ends in `failure (Permission denied)`.

Am I supposed to be doing this local to remote sync? Or am I off base here? If I'm on base, why do I get permission denied?

Comment: Typically you use a version control system (eg git) to update the files on your server

Comment: [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is a tool commonly used in the Unix world to keep directories synced (it's also available for Windows). It can easily run through an SSH tunnel so information travels encrypted.

Comment: Is rsync meant to work in conjunction with Git? Or is it one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the user you're using for the SFTP connection has read permissions on the folder you're working on, but is not allowed to write.
For this reason, you were allowed to download your remote folder, but no longer allowed to write in it (upload).

You can check this by running `ls -ld /path/to/rails/` and reading the first part (for example, it could be `drwxr--r--`). If needed, [here you can learn more about file system permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Notation_of_traditional_Unix_permissions).

If it's a permission problem, you can solve it in different ways, but you should consider how each solution could impact the security and/or functionality of your application:

- You could change the owner of the rails directory to match the Sublime SFTP user (see `man chown`), and ensure the owner of the rails user has write access on it (`sudo chmod o+w /path/to/rails`)
- You could use a different user for Sublime SFTP access (one that has write permissions on the rails folder)
- You could add the Sublime SFTP user to the group of the rails folder (`useradd -G {group-name} username`) and then grant the folder group write access (`sudo chmod g+w /path/to/rails`)